# Ajax readyState always equals one

Tags: javascript, ajax, cgi

Hello I'm working with ajax that submits to a C++ cgi program. The problem that I am having is the readyState is always 1. I don't get what I am doing wrong.

```
    var asyncRequest; // XMLHttpRequest object

    try
        {
            asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Register event handler
            asyncRequest.onreadystatechange = StateChange; 

            // Prepare to post data to URL asynchronously
            asyncRequest.open("POST", "save_vote.cgi", true); 

            //Data to be sent to cgi program
            postData="star=1&movie=test";


            // Set the appropriate HTTP request headers
            asyncRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            asyncRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);

            // Make request
            asyncRequest.send(postData);

         }
         catch (exception)
         {
            alert("Request failed: " + exception.message);
         }

}
function StateChange()
{

    // Make sure request has completed with 200 OK status

    //alert(asyncRequest.status)
    if (asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200)
    {
        alert("Hello");
    }

}
```

Here is the cgi program

```
#include "cgi.h"
#include <fstream>
    int main()
{
    cout << "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

    ParseInputParameters();

    ofstream fout;

    if (fout.fail())
    {
        cout << "CGI Error - Couldn't open file for appending for appending.";
        return 0;
    }


    //message to be sent back in the response text
        cout << "OK";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the shown code the EXACT code? What's before `var asyncRequest;`? If it's a function, the `asyncRequest` variable is privately wrapped, and the `asyncRequest` variable in `function ReadyState(){}` does not represent the expected XHR object.

Comment: Yes its in a function called ajaxUpdate. Not much is before that just the function name. So what would be the solution for the asyncRequest variable to represented in the readyState function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the SateChange function to the body of the function where the XHR is being made. After this modification, the `asyncRequest` inside `StateChange` will equal the relevant `asyncRequest` object.

```
function ajaxUpdate(){
    ....
    var asyncRequest; // XMLHttpRequest object
    try {
        asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ....
        asyncRequest.send(postData);
     }
     catch (exception){
        alert("Request failed: " + exception.message);
     }

    //} <---Removed curly bracket
    function StateChange(){

        // Make sure request has completed with 200 OK status

        //alert(asyncRequest.status)
        if (asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200){
            alert("Hello");
        }
    }

} //<--Added curly bracket!
```