# Redy state object null or undefined for simple ajax

Tags: ajax

I have created a very simple program for AJAX object creation.

```
<script>
function fun1(){

if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorar")
{
obj=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.xmlhttp");
}
else
{
obj= new XMLHttpRequest();
}

obj.open("post","page1.php",true);
obj.send();
alert (obj.redyState);
obj.onredystatechange=function () {
alert ("hi");
if(obj.readyState==4)
alert("hi1");
}

}

</script>

<button onclick="fun1()">click</button>
```

But alert message within the function are not displaying.

And "alert (obj.redyState);" shows [undefined] as output on IE and blank message box in Firefox.

What may be the issue?

Comment: Typo. Perhaps `alert(obj.readyState)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's spelled ready not redy.  This goes for everything.  For example:

```
onredystatechange
```

should be

```
onreadystatechange
```

Comment: yes that was correct. But even after spelling it correctly somehow readyState remains 1. its not becoming 4. What may be the issue?

Comment: Then, you need to do some more debugging of your code.

Comment: I tried debugging,and also gave correct output. But only once it was correctly executed. When retrying I found readyState is again stuck at 1. No code issue this time. What may be the problem? Server is working on port number 8080 ,is this creating issue?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861447/ajax-readystate-always-equals-one

Answer (score 0):

that's not redystatechange.. It is "readystatechange"

```
obj.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  alert ("hi");
if(obj.readyState==4)
alert("hi1");
  }
```